# How do you pass parameters to a function passed as a keyword argument?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter button that who's command calls a function that takes an argument, in this case the function is taking the tkinter window as an argument.

```py
from tkinter import *

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.update()

def do_something(tk_win):
    # Do something to the window

class Application(Frame):
    master = None

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.btn = Button(self, text="Redo Search", command=do_something, self)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.search_again.pack()
```

The line where I assign `btn`'s value is getting flagged by my IDE saying "Positional argument follows keyword argument". I understand why it's saying that but I can't figure out how to pass self as a parameter to the function. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you passing `self` twice? It looks to me like you can just pass it as the first argument if you want it assigned to `Button.master`. If you want it assigned to something else, pass it as a keyword argument.

Comment: Simple, remove the self from the function

    self.btn = Button(self, text="Redo Search", command=do_something)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass the second `self` as an argument to `do_something` when it's called, you can create a zero-argument function that in turn calls `do_something` with the desired single argument when invoked.

One way to do that is with a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions):

```
self.btn = Button(self, text="Redo Search", command=lambda: do_something(self))
```

...whereas another is to use the [`functools.partial` helper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) (in the `functools` module) to generate a "partially evaluated" function for the purpose:

```
self.btn = Button(self, text="Redo Search", command=functools.partial(do_something, self))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, remove the self from the function

```
self.btn = Button(self, text="Redo Search", command=lambda: do_something(self))
```

Comment: Does this pass `self` to `do_something`, as the OP intends?

Answer (score 0):

Would the alteration below work for your design?  Make the function part of the class, and call it "normally" with the "self-dot" syntax.

```
class Application(Frame):
    master = None

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    ### Pull the function into the class
    def do_something(self):
        # Do something to the window
        ...

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        ### Call the function with straightforward syntax
        self.btn = Button(self, text="Redo Search", command=self.do_something)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.search_again.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

By using do_something(self) finction.

Return a new partial object which when called will behave like func called with the positional arguments args and keyword arguments keywords. If more arguments are supplied to the call, they are appended to args. If additional keyword arguments are supplied, they extend and override keywords. Roughly equivalent to:

def partial(func, args, *keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*args, fargs, *newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc